# Is there a way to import private keys from the Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys folder?

Tags: c#, cryptography, x509certificate2

I'm looking to interact with the private keys folder (essentially to find a private key to try to pair to a public key, given that a public key isn't paired with one already ) certutil -repairstore functionality is basically what I'm looking for - I believe being able to use code to iterate over the private keys would help me achieve this

Simply trying to read all bytes from these files and import them as a Cspblob into a RSACryptoProvider does not work. Gives a "bad version of provider" error.

```
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

startInfo.Arguments = @"/C certutil -repairstore my " + selectedCertificate.Thumbprint;

startInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

Is my current work-around command line usage, but I don't prefer to use the command line where possible - This isn't an object I can use or manipulate, it just has similar functionality to what I want to end up doing.

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/777290/68215)?

Comment: Hmm, a bit over my head, but thank you. I'll try making sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the small test code snippet. At offset 0x28 there's a container name that can be used to load Key parameters. I couldn't find any documentation regarding private key file format so it might not work in all cases.

```
public static RSAParameters LoadParametersFromFile(string fileName)
{
    int provType = 1;
    string provName = "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0"

    // Load key container name;
    StringBuilder containerName = new StringBuilder();
    using (var keyFile = File.OpenRead(fileName))
    {
        keyFile.Position = 0x28;
        int c;
        while ((c = keyFile.ReadByte()) != 0 && c !=-1) containerName.Append((char) c);
    }

    CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(provType, provName);
    csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore; // set it accordingly
    csp.KeyContainerName = containerName.ToString();
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp))
    {
        RSAParameters loadedParams = rsaKey.ExportParameters(false);
        return loadedParams;
    }
}
```

Test call:

```
var rsaParams =  LoadParametersFromFile(@"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\0034dc1b91df7f7d75df774fa568bc73_ba648dc7-2ead-41db-8cde-e6f84e3fb1cc");
```

*rsaParams.Modulus* will contain the public key.