# Read key file located in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

One of utility we created generates too many files in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys. To safely delete these files I want to open each file and exam the key. How can I open these key files in C#? I looked at code at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411242/is-there-a-way-to-import-private-keys-from-the-microsoft-crypto-rsa-machinekeys). The code only returns public key. Can I get more information form these key files?

Comment: You need to find the certificates that key originated.  You do not want to store public and private keys in a non trusted located so hackers cannot get both the public and private keys.  The key is file in the Program Data folder and you may need admin privilege to open file.

Comment: I have the certificate and password that key originated. The root cause of this problem is I import the certificate every time I use it instead of importing it into certificate store. I have changed the way the utility works. Now it doesn't generate new key files anymore.

Comment: You are correct.  Every time you create a new document a new public key should be generated from the certificate (private key).  So you have to import the certificate to get the new public key.

Comment: How am I going to import these file? There is no extension. What's the format?

Comment: You have the certificate.  Why do you want to import the files?

Comment: I want to import files generated automatically at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys. I need to check cert property so I can delete files safely.

Comment: You can only check certificate at the time the documents are generated.  You should delete these files immediately after the checks are completed.  You do not want to keep old public keys which a hacker can access.  There is no way that a public key can be reversed to find private key.  It would defeat the purpose of public/private key architecture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203051/discussion-between-luyin-sun-and-jdweng).

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using following powershell to get a list of valid key from certificate store. I also added c2319c42033a5ca7f44e731bfd3fa2b5 to the list since I am using IIS service. I delete any key file not in this list.

```
 $MachineCertStores = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine
$UserCertStores = Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser

Foreach ($Store in $MachineCertStores)
{
    $path = "Cert:\LocalMachine\" + $($store.Name)
    $keys = Get-ChildItem $path
    Foreach ($Key in $Keys)
        {
        $UniqueKeyName = $key.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName
        if ([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($UniqueKeyName)){
        }else{
            write-host $UniqueKeyName
            $file = Get-Content "validkey.txt"
            $containsWord = $file | %{$_ -match $UniqueKeyName.substring(0,32)}
            If($containsWord -contains $true)
            {
            }else{
                $UniqueKeyName.substring(0,32) | Out-File 'validkey.txt' -Append
            }
        }
    }
}

Foreach ($Store in $UserCertStores)
{
    $path = "Cert:\CurrentUser\" + $($store.Name)
    $keys = Get-ChildItem $path
    Foreach ($Key in $Keys)
        {
        $UniqueKeyName = $key.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName
        if ([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($UniqueKeyName)){
        }else{
            write-host $UniqueKeyName
            $file = Get-Content "validkey.txt"
            $containsWord = $file | %{$_ -match $UniqueKeyName.substring(0,32)}
            If($containsWord -contains $true)
            {
            }else{
                $UniqueKeyName.substring(0,32) | Out-File 'validkey.txt' -Append
            }
        }
    }
}
```